# convert or filter a `Task` from `Some` to `Left` with `fp-ts`

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts, io-ts-library

I'm trying to learn how to use type guards and predicted functions with `io-ts` | `fp-ts`, and what I need to do the following:

I've this function:

```
    createOne: ({ password, ...creatableUser }: CreatableUser): taskEither.TaskEither<ExceptionError, User> => {
      ....
    }
```

And it'll need to:

1. Check if the user email doesn't exists
2. Create an user with the given data
3. Send an email to the new user
   So I need something like:

```
// * Doubt Function 
export const createOne = ({ password, ...creatableUserData }: CreatableUser): taskEither.TaskEither<Error, User> => {
  // Generate the new user
  const newUser: User = {
    ...creatableUserData,
    id: randomUUID(),
  };

  return pipe(
    // * Check that the user doesn't exists yet
    creatableUserData.email,
    findByEmail,
    taskEither.fromTaskOption(() => new Error('User already exists')), // TODO: need to return a error on `Some`
    // * Save the new `User` on the repository
    taskEither.chain(() => save(newUser, password)),
    // * Send the confirmation email to the user
    taskEither.chain(() =>
      sendMail({
        body: 'Welcome to App Team',
      }),
    ),
    taskEither.map(() => newUser),
  );
};
```

I need to 'parse' the response from `taskOption.Some` to a `taskEither.Left`, but i don't find a way to do that

Here the types for a better context:

```
import { randomUUID } from 'crypto';
import { TaskOption } from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskOption';
import { taskEither } from 'fp-ts';
import { TaskEither } from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

// * Types for context
type CreatableUser = {
  password: string;
  email: string;
  //...
}
type User = {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  //...
}

declare const findByEmail: (email: string) => TaskOption<User>;
declare const save: (user: User, password: string) => TaskEither<Error, void>;
declare const sendMail: (message: {body: string}) => TaskEither<Error, void>;
```

Someone has some idea to how do filter or use a predicted function do early return if the user already exists?

### Update

I was able to fix this issue with the following code:

```
export const makeCreateOne =
  (usersRepository: UsersRepository, mailProvider: MailProvider) =>
  ({ password, ...creatableUserData }: CreatableUser): TaskEither<ExceptionError, User> => {
    // Generate the new user
    const newUser: User = {
      ...creatableUserData,
      id: randomUUID(),
    };


    return pipe(
      // * Get the user with the given email
      creatableUserData.email,
      usersRepository.findByEmail,
      // * Return `null` if `Some`
      TO.match(
        // TODO: improve that
        // None: The user doesn't exists, we can create a new user
        () => true,
        // Some: The user already exists, so we don't wanna keep the creation process
        () => null,
      ),
      TE.fromNullable(createExceptionError('User already exists', REQUEST_STATUS.not_found)),
      // * Save the new `User` on the repository
      TE.chain(() => usersRepository.save(newUser, password)),
      // * Send the confirmation email to the user
      TE.chain(() =>
        mailProvider.sendMail({
          body: 'Welcome to App Team',
        }),
      ),
      TE.map(() => newUser),
    );
  };
```

But still, doesn't look great, if someone had some idea to how to improve I appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone had the same doubt, here my solution:
I figure out that at this point makes sense to create a method just to validate if the email is available, so I create this interface:

```
export type UsersRepository = {
  readonly findByEmail: (email: string) => TaskOption<User>;
  readonly findByID: (id: string) => TaskOption<User>;

  readonly save: (user: User, password: string) => TaskEither<ExceptionError, void>;
  readonly update: (user: User, password?: string) => TaskEither<ExceptionError, void>;
  readonly delete: (userID: ID) => TaskEither<ExceptionError, void>;

  readonly all: () => TaskEither<ExceptionError, ReadonlyArray<User>>;

  readonly isUserPasswordValid: (email: string, password: string) => Task<boolean>;
  readonly isEmailAvailable: (email: string) => Task<Boolean>;
};
```

And refactor the function to works like:

```
export const makeCreateOne =
  (usersRepository: UsersRepository, mailProvider: MailProvider) =>
  ({ password, ...creatableUserData }: CreatableUser): TaskEither<ExceptionError, User> => {
    // Generate the new user
    const newUser: User = {
      ...creatableUserData,
      id: randomUUID(),
    };

    return pipe(
      // * Get the user with the given email
      creatableUserData.email,
      usersRepository.isEmailAvailable,
      TE.fromTask,
      TE.filterOrElse(
        isEmailAvailable => isEmailAvailable,
        () => createExceptionError('Check your password and try again', REQUEST_STATUS.bad),
      ),
      // * Save the new `User` on the repository
      TE.chain(() => usersRepository.save(newUser, password)),
      // * Send the confirmation email to the user
      TE.chain(() =>
        mailProvider.sendMail({
          body: 'Welcome to App Team',
        }),
      ),
      TE.map(() => newUser),
    );
  };
```